# Error 404 Not Found ml5.js.map p5.sound.js.map using PoseNet & ml5

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, processing, p5.js

I'm currently working on a ml5.js application using PoseNet.js & p5. When I deploy the app through node's http-server, my PoseNet model doesn't work and I get these errors on my cmd:

```
"GET /p5.sound.min.js.map" Error (404): "Not found"
"GET /ml5.min.js.map" Error (404): "Not found"
```

And these on Chromes console:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://[ip address]/ml5.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE 

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://[ip address]/p5.sound.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I don't really understand what .map is referencing to and I can't find any information on p5's website mentioning I need to reference it. I also don't understand why I need p5.sound.js when my application doesn't require sound. 
My html code referencing the libraries currently looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ml5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="modelDeploy.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
```

The most confusing thing of all is that it sometimes works, it sometimes doesn't, and it sometimes works for a bit then crashes with those errors and I haven't been able to figure out why. Please let me know if the whole html/js code is needed. I'm just starting out so my explanation/understanding might be all over the place sorry :) 
Any help will be much appreciated :D

Comment: You have p5.min.js, ml5.min.js in the same folder as your html file, right ? Running `http-server` in that folder should also statically serve the files within it...assuming you use the default port (8080), does http://localhost:8080/ml5.min.js.map load ? (TBH if http://localhost:8080/ml5.min.js loads, don't worry too mouch about the .map file unless you're doing running a JS debugger). If you don't require p5.sound simply remove it from `<head>` (probably same for p5.dom ?) The crash makes no sense though, maybe it's something else ? Have you tried other options(p5 editor/glitch/etc)

Comment: Try it: it it works with the online p5.js libs, should work with them offline. (can try with the online p5.js editor, glitch, (even adding p5.js as a CDNJS external library to stackoverflow's snippet editor) etc.). If everything is setup correctly the only gotcha in running it locally but offline would be PoseNet (which may need some changes).
re: DOM: see [p5.dom reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#group-DOM). It's useful if you need to create/manipulate HTML elements from p5.js.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! @GeorgeProfenza yes, I have both in the same folder. localhost:8080/ml5.min.js.map does not load but localhost:8080/ml5.min.js does. By crash I mean my model initially works but stops after a minute or so. I've tried glitch and my model doesn't work and the ml5.min.js error still persists. Could it be a network error? My wifi hasn't been very good lately. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/yogai this is the glitch link if helpful :)

Comment: That sounds like the issue is not 404 related: otherwise (if anything required would've failed to load) the model wouldn't have initially worked at all. If the error occurs after a minute, perhaps it's a memory leak ? check what objects you create when using`draw()` / `setInterval()`/etc. (btw, you never seem to use `clearInterval`(perhaps it's setTimeout you're after ?), double check you don't accidentally create many overlapping intervals). [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems) should help with that too. Happy debugging !

Comment: Again on the Dev Tools, keep eye on the JS Console for errors and the Network tab if you're worried about external files not loading. (Firefox and other browsers have similar developer tools)